# Need help choosing best paypal solution to reduce PCI burden to "SAQ A" for this donation form?

Tags: paypal

I have a client that has a form on their website that accepts donations using Paypal's "Transparent Redirect", which puts them in the SAQ A-EP category for PCI compliance. 
They would like to be in SAQ A (the least burdensome category) and I'm wondering which integration to choose to accomplish that.
* "SAQ A" can only be achieved with an iframe or a straight up redirect to a payment form hosted by Paypal or whatever PCI compliant entity.

Here are the requirements for the form:

1. Donors can give using their credit/debit card.
2. Donors can choose up to 10 pre-defined designations (from a list of about 100) and specify whatever amount they want for each...so a collection of donations, like a shopping cart of products. For example: ($90 to Fund A, $200 to Fund B..)
3. It can be a one time payment (default), or monthly recurring. (This would apply to the entire "cart"...not individual items.)
4. Recurring billing would be done programatically. (The client would not have to set these up manually.)
5. The donations must continue to be deposited into that gateway / merchant account they are using now, which is a "Paypal Gateway" account.

I have spent some time on this and every solution I've looked at either doesn't support one of the requirements, or I can't find all the information I need, or there
is conflicting documentation, or my concentration is broken by thoughts of shoving a spoon into my eye so i can go home.

So far my two best guesses are:

1. "PayPal Payments Advanced" with "Hosted Pages"

   - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/paypal-payments-advanced/
   - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/
2. Braintree's "Hosted Fields" solution. - I'm pretty sure they can meet requirements 1-4 but I'm not sure about 5.
   Also not sure what the additional cost might be...just seems silly to have to go to a third party for something as seemingly simple as this.